# Create json containing all titles from group by query result

Tags: php, group-by, group-concat

I am trying to do very simple stuff but can't get it to work. I see some complex similar thread here but I can't get it around those.

I simplified my issue so I have just one table with two rows. Products and title. Products have similar name but title doesn't and I want to get it in json but I am stuck on way to simply get the all the titles. Here my code

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT* FROM mylist GROUP BY products");
while($row = $query->fetch_array()){
echo $row['products'].' - '; 
echo $row['title'];
echo "<br>";
```

The result I get is this

```
prod1 - title 4
prod2 - title 2
prod3 - title 3
```

But I am expecting this

```
prod1 - title 4, title 1
prod2 - title 2
prod3 - title 3
```

Then encode it in json

UPDATE:
So I am able to get JSON like this

```
{"prod1":["title 4,title 1"],"prod2":["title 2"],"prod3":["title 3"]}
```

With this code

```
$request = <<< EOT
SELECT products, GROUP_CONCAT(title) AS title
FROM mylist
GROUP BY products
ORDER BY products ASC;
EOT;

$rows = $con->query($request)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$items= array();
foreach ($rows as $row){
    $days[$row['products']]= explode(",", $row['title']);
}
var_dump($items);
echo json_encode($items);
```

But I am still looking for some minor tweak. How can I get json like this

```
{
"prodlist": {
    "prod1": [
        {
            "title": "title5"
        },
        {
            "title": "title1"
        }
    ],
    "prod2": [
        {
            "title": "title5"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Try using GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: Yeah, thanks but not sure if its best way and also not sure how to add another row $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT products, GROUP_CONCAT(title)as title FROM mylist GROUP BY products");

Answer (score 0):

You need `GROUP_CONCAT` like this

```
SELECT products, GROUP_CONCAT(title ORDER BY products ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS prods 
FROM mylist  
GROUP BY products
```

Here is the full SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38681/7

Comment: Yep, that works but its very limited to just two rows, How do I add more rows like price, url, description, etc

Comment: `SELECT products, GROUP_CONCAT(title,price,url ORDER BY products ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS prods 
FROM mylist  
GROUP BY products`

Comment: `prod1 - title 46,title 13
prod2 - title 24
prod3 - title 35`

Comment: but expectation is like this

Comment: `prod1 - title 4,6;title 1,3;
prod2 - title 2,4;
prod3 - title 3,5`;